# jQuery Select Check Box with Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple bit of jquery which is running a trigger on click of a radio button to check my check boxes.

```
    <script>
        jQuery('#op5').click(function () {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');                

        });
    </script>
```

These are my checkboxes they have labels to give them a custom style.

```
<input type="checkbox" certificate="true" checked="checked" id="gridcb0" siteid="1381" value="72218" class="custom selector checkedFocus">
<label for="gridcb0" class="white">&nbsp;</label>
```

And this is the radio button I am clicking to check the checkboxes

```
<input type="radio" id="op5" value="1" name="options2" class="custom">
```

However it is not checking my check boxes on first click it requires me to click on the radio button op5 twice to check the boxes, I do not want to run the line below twice to highlight these check boxes

```
<input type="radio" id="op5" value="1" name="options2" class="custom">
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prop()` property and add value `checked` instead of trigger click
If you are using jQuery 1.6+

```
jQuery('#op5').click(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: `attr` expects a string value and changes the literal DOM attribute. You should use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value) instead which will correctly change the property

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
jQuery('#op5').click(function () {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery you are using

For jQuery 1.6+, Use the new .prop() function and for jQuery 1.5.x and below, use .attr() function

```
// jQuery 1.6+
$('#op5').click(function () {
    $('#gridcb0').prop('checked', true);
});

// jQuery 1.5.x and below
$('#op5').click(function () {
    $('#gridcb0').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Check this post for more details - 
[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try prop() and trigger():

Since you have id, you can use id selector

```
$('#gridcb0').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
```

If you still want to target all checkbox:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
```